# circuitikz weird Undefined control sequence

Tags: draw

The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (1,0) to[short, i<=2] (1.5,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

gives an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@anchor ->\pgf@circ@dir
```

If I change e.g., to

```
\draw (0.8,0) to[short, i<=2] (1.5,-2);
```

or I remove the `i<=2` it compiles fine. I use a standard installation of macTeX on macOS 10.12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.  Until it is fixed you can use

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\let\pgf@circ@dir=\pgf@circ@direction
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (1,0) to[short, i<=2] (1.5,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I get the same error (after considering your suggestions).

Comment: If you are still getting the error, you should update your packages.  I update every week.

Comment: I removed mactex-2015 (deleted /usr/local/texlive/2015) and installed mactex-20161009 but I keep getting the same error (with or without your suggestion).

Comment: It seems that fetching the latest mactex was not enough. After updating using the "tex live utility" the problem was solved (using \makeatletter ... \makeatother). Thanks for the help.